# Dagger 2 inject method

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm playing around with [Dagger 2](http://google.github.io/dagger/).

I have the following `Module`:

```
@Module
public class GameSetupModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    GameSetup provideGameSetup() {
        return new GameSetup();
    }
}
```

and the according `Component`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {GameSetupModule.class})
public interface GameSetupComponent {
    GameSetup provideGameSetup();

    void inject(SetupActivity activity);

//    void inject(Fragment fragment);

    void inject(SetupCompletedFragment fragment);

    void inject(SelectQuarterLengthFragment fragment);

    void inject(SelectTeamColorsFragment fragment);

    void inject(SelectUserRoleFragment fragment);

}
```

As you can see the GameSetup is to injected into several different Fragments like this:

```
@Inject
GameSetup gameSetup; 

onCreate(){
   getGameSetupComponent().inject(this); 
}
```

It works fine when implemented as seen above, the injection does not work though when I just use a single method

```
 void inject(Fragment fragment);
```

for all Fragments.

Am I doing something wrong or is this even intended to have more control over *where* the `GameSetup` may be injected and where it may not be available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dagger2 does not support base class injections out of the box.

A method such as `void inject(Fragment fragment);` would only inject the fields that are specified with `@Inject` within the `Fragment` class, and not its subclasses.

According to jackhexen on Reddit, what you are doing [*is* possible to do with reflection](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3f0aso/dagger2_injection_through_a_base_class/). But reflection can break Proguard.

I personally would vote for [this solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3f0aso/dagger2_injection_through_a_base_class/ctk7x49).