# Is the inject method a reserved name? how Dagger-2 knows to implement its body?

Tags: java, dagger-2

I've seen this snippet:

```
@Component(modules = {TestActivityModule.class})
public interface TestActivityComponent {
    void inject(TestActivity activity);
}
```

But the `inject` method is not implemented in user code (but auto-generated in `Dagger-2` code).

So is the `inject` a reserved name? how `Dagger-2` knows to implement this method?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961094/dagger-2-inject-method

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie, I saw that, it doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got it: the name doesn't matter, it can be e.g. `squeeze`, as long as the provided type contains `@Inject` fields(s)/methods(s)/constructor(s), `Dagger-2` will generate the method's body:

```
@Component(modules = {TypoModule.class})
public interface TypoComponent {
    void squeeze(Thingie t);
}
```

...and as long as there's a `@Provides` that returns the `@Inject`ed type:

```
@Module class TypoModule {
    @Provides InjectedType whateverNameYouDecide() {
        return new InjectedSubType();
        // InjectedSubType extends InjectedType, obviously...
    }
}
```

Of course, `Thingie` should have `@Inject`ed member or nothing will happen:

```
class Thingie {
    @Inject InjectedType thingieID;
}
```

That's the whole story...

Comment: Exactly. Naming is just convention and readability. You don't have to call it component or module either

Comment: `inject` (or `squeeze` or whatever`) is a "members injection method".  The contract is documented in the [@Component javadoc](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#members-injection-methods).